# Epsilon delta proof of a simple sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Determine whether the following sequences converge or diverge. Prove
your findings. That is, (directly or indirectly, by contradiction) provide
an $\epsilon$ − N proof to establish your findings.

(a) $\{ \frac{n^4-1}{n^4+n-6}\}$. I know it converges to one just by setting the limit but I don't get how to do the proof. My attempt:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $ N > 0$, such that for all $n \in N$, if $n > N$, then $|\frac{n^4-1}{n^4+n-6} - 1| = \frac{|-n+5|}{|n^4+n-6|} = \frac{|n-5|}{|n^4+n-6|} \leq \frac{|n-5|}{n^4}$. I'm lost.

Comment: You could estimate the enumerator from above by $n$ since only large numbers $n$ are interesting.

Comment: Like.. finding a maximum? (I forgot how to do that)

Comment: Hmm? For $n\ge 5$ you have $|n-5| = n-5\le n$. Dividing by $n^4$ you get $1/n^3$. Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ by given and find $N$ such that $1/N^3 < \varepsilon$. BTW: There is no $\delta$ involved as the title suggests.

Comment: What would N =, I mean don't i have to say something about N if I let it be n >= 5? Would N = min(1/e^3,5) work?

Comment: Almost. First, take the $\max$ instead of the $\min$. Second, why $\varepsilon^3$?

Comment: max($1/e^{1/3}, 5)$. yeah uhm, like this?

Comment: Yupp. Very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to show that $g(n)=1-n^{-4}$ and $h(n)= n^{-3}-6n^{-4}$ each converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

So $(n^4-1)/(n^4+n-6)-1=(1+g(n))/(1+h(n))-1= (g(n)-h(n))/(1+h(n)).$

If $n$ is large enough that $\max (|g(n)|,|h(n)|)<\min (e/4,1/2)$ then $$|1+h(n)|=1+h(n)>1/2 \quad\text{ and } \quad|g(n)-h(n)|\leq |g(n)|+|h(n)|<e/2$$ so $|g(n)-h(n)|/|1+h(n)|<(e/2)/(1/2)=e.$

Answer (score 0):

I will post the scratch work, because I think this is where the biggest challenges come in, once this is done, constructing the proof is straight forward from the definition of convergence:

$$ \left\lvert \dfrac{n^4 - 1}{n^4 + n - 6} -1\right\rvert  < \epsilon$$

$$ \left\lvert \dfrac{n -5}{n^4 +n-6} \right\rvert = \dfrac{\left\lvert n -5 \right\rvert}{\left\lvert n^4 +n-6 \right\rvert} = \dfrac{n+5 }{\left\lvert n^4 +n-6 \right\rvert} \leq \dfrac{X}{Y}< \epsilon$$

Okay, we've simplified this enough just enough to make some moves. Note that we used the triangle inequality ($\lvert a \pm b \rvert \leq \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert$) for the numerator.

Our goal now is to figure out what $\dfrac{X}{Y}$ is and we will do this based on the information we have. Notice that in the numerator we can write $ n+5 \leq n + n $ for what $n$ is this true? ($ n \geq 5$, keep track of this somewhere). So let's update our expression:

$$ \dfrac{n+5 }{\left\lvert n^4 +n-6 \right\rvert} \leq \dfrac{2n}{Y}< \epsilon $$

Now let's look at the denominator.

If we increased that 6 to some number greater than 6, then the  denominator that we have would get smaller. So let's write this out as

$$ \lvert n^4 + n - 6 \rvert \geq \lvert n^4 + n - n \rvert \quad \text{for} \quad  n\geq6 $$
$$ \dfrac{1}{\lvert n^4 + n - 6 \rvert} \leq \dfrac{1}{\lvert n^4 + n - n \rvert} \quad \text{for} \quad  n\geq6 $$

So now we have

$$ \dfrac{n+5 }{\left\lvert n^4 +n-6 \right\rvert} \leq \dfrac{2n}{ n^4 } < \dfrac{1}{n^3}< \epsilon $$

So what should/could you choose for your $N$ to be? How about $N = \left\lceil \dfrac{1}{\epsilon ^{1/3}} \right\rceil$. And we include the symbols $\lceil X \rceil$ to signify that we always round up in such a way that whatever we chose for $N$.

But wait! We forgot that to get this expression, we had to impose some extra restrictions, remember?

So instead, let $N = max\left\{ \left\lceil \dfrac{1}{\epsilon ^{1/3}} \right\rceil , 6\right\}$ so that our assumptions and assertions are all covered.